# css full screen width div within a pixel width for responsive site

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Here is what I have going on. I have my pages structured with a #wrap div and the pages content within that wrap in a #content div and then a special block of content within that div.Both css and html below. My question is, is there a way to have my screen-width-content div span outside of the 1140px width of the .wrap div that it is in. I know if I could I could simply move the div but long story short, I cannot change the HTML, only the css. Also the site is a responsive design so it has to stay that way. Solutions Anyone.

CSS

```
.wrap {
   margin: 0 auto;
   width: 1140px;
   }

.content {
   padding: 0;
   width: 100%;
   }

#screen-width-content {
   width: 100%;
   margin: 0 auto;
   }
```

HTML

```
<div class="wrap">
   <div class="content">
      my pages content
       <div id="screen-width-content">
         screen width content
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edited the answer and seems to work:

have a look at this example, maybe it helps: http://jsfiddle.net/fR4mN/3/

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>animate demo</title>
<style>
.wrap {
    margin:0 auto;
    background-color:orange;
    width:400px;
    height:700px;
    position:relative;
}
.inner {
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    height:200px;
    background-color:gold;
}
.inner-outer {
    position:absolute;
    height:100px;
    background-color:green;
}
</style>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="inner">
        <div class="inner-outer"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="inner-outer"></div>
</div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        setCheckSpaceDistance();
        $(window).resize(function() {
            setCheckSpaceDistance();
        });
    });
    function setCheckSpaceDistance() {
        var dist = $('.wrap').position().left;
        $('.inner-outer').css({
            'width' : dist+'px',
            'right' : '-'+dist+'px'
        });
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry but I need the .inner-outer div (in your example) to be edge to edge of the screen size and responsive, so percent based.

Comment: @DaveC is jQuery an option?

Answer (score 0):

You could change the width of `#screen-width-content` to anything greater than 100% - depending on how much you want it outside of the wrapper.

And like the comment says below, use negative `margin-left` to position it accordingly.

Hope this helps!

Comment: And acompany that with as much negative margin-left as you want

Comment: How would I insure that it is responsive? If I made it lets say 300% how would I insure that it is edge to edge of the browser window for all viewers.

Comment: You will have to change the width of the wrap from a pixel value to a percentage value. This is because the 1140px is fixed and doesn't change with browser size.

Comment: Yes that is my dilemma, I cannot change that to percentage. I need it pixel based as my whole design is based around it. I have a max-width media screen in my css to change the 1140px to percentage once it hits a 1200px cut off. This is for when it is bigger then that.

Comment: Well at the 1200px cut off you should change the `#screen-width-content` percentage width to fit the new screen width.